# Generate XML tree with values using py script

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I am new to python and would like to create XML tree with values.

I want to put both jsc://xxx.js" files as well as "EXT.FC.XML" under resource & policy element in XML via python code. All jsc://xxx.js" and "EXT.FC.XML" files are stored in my local folder named "resources" and "policies".

The desired output

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<APIProxy revision="2" name="Retirement_Digital_Account_Balance">
    <ManifestVersion>SHA-512:f9ae03c39bf00f567559e</ManifestVersion>
    <Policies>
        <Policy>EXT.FC_Env_Host</Policy>
        <Policy>EXT.FC_JWTVerf</Policy>
        <Policy>EXT.JSC_Handle_Fault</Policy>
    </Policies>
    <ProxyEndpoints>
        <ProxyEndpoint>default</ProxyEndpoint>
    </ProxyEndpoints>
    <Resources>
        <Resource>jsc://createErrorMessage.js</Resource>
        <Resource>jsc://jwtHdrExt.js</Resource>
        <Resource>jsc://log-variables.js</Resource>
        <Resource>jsc://swagger.json</Resource>
        <Resource>jsc://tgtDataForm.js</Resource>
    </Resources>
</APIProxy>
```

I use Element tree for converting into xml file, this is the code I run

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import Element, SubElement, Comment
from xml.etree import ElementTree, cElementTree
from xml.dom import minidom
from ElementTree_pretty import prettify
import datetime
import os

generated_on = str(datetime.datetime.now())
#proxy = Element('APIProxy')
proxy = Element('APIProxy', revision = "2", name = "Retirement_Digital_Account_Balance")

ManifestVersion = SubElement(proxy, 'ManifestVersion')
ManifestVersion.text = 'SHA-512:f9ae03c39bf00f567559e'

Policies = SubElement(proxy, 'Policies')
Policy = SubElement(Policies, 'Policy')

path = '/policies'
#files = []
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if '.xml' in file:
            Policy.append(os.path.join(r, file))

    for p in Policy:
        print(p)

ProxyEndpoints = SubElement(proxy, 'ProxyEndpoints')
ProxyEndpoint = SubElement(ProxyEndpoints, 'ProxyEndpoint')
ProxyEndpoint.text = 'default'

Resources = SubElement(proxy, 'Resources')
Resource = SubElement(Resources, 'Resource')
path = '/Resources'
# r=root, d=directories, f = files
for r, d, f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        if 'js' in file:
            Resource.append(os.path.join(r, file))

    for R in Resource:
        print(R)

Spec = SubElement(proxy, 'Spec')
Spec.text = ""
#proxy.append(Spec)

proxy.append(Element('TargetServers'))

TargetEndpoints = SubElement(proxy, 'TargetEndpoints')
TargetEndpoint = SubElement(TargetEndpoints, 'TargetEndpoint')
TargetEndpoint.text = 'default'

print(ET.tostring(proxy))
tree = cElementTree.ElementTree(proxy) # wrap it in an ElementTree instance, and save as XML

t = minidom.parseString(ElementTree.tostring(proxy)).toprettyxml() # Since ElementTree write() has no pretty printing support, used minidom to beautify the xml.
tree1 = ElementTree.ElementTree(ElementTree.fromstring(t))

tree1.write("Retirement_Digital_Account_Balance_v2.xml",encoding='UTF-8', xml_declaration=True)
```

Okay, the code is working but i didnt get the desired output, I got the following:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<APIProxy name="Retirement_Digital_Account_Balance" revision="2">
    <ManifestVersion>SHA-512:f9ae03c39bf00f567559e</ManifestVersion>
    <Policies>
        <Policy />
    </Policies>
    <ProxyEndpoints>
        <ProxyEndpoint>default</ProxyEndpoint>
    </ProxyEndpoints>
    <Resources>
        <Resource />
    </Resources>
</APIProxy>
```

How to use loop in ElementTree in python to import the values from folder and create XML tree with its values?

Comment: What is the difference between this question and these two other ones of yours: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60745400/generate-sample-xml-structure-using-py-script, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60732099/how-to-iterate-over-xml-tags-in-python-using-elementtree ?

Comment: They're not identical, but they all seem to revolve around the same problem.

Comment: @AMC i apologize. but they all are quite same usecase but with some more debugging that i have made. This time you will get more clarity.